# Redirect via htacces to error pages (not found & Internal Server error)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, custom-error-pages

can I vía .htaccess redirect when

- Users finds an Internal Server Error
- A not found page

Is that posible? if so, can someone help me with the rewrite rules?

edit

trying

```
ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
ErrorDocument 404 /where.php
```

and adding them at domain.com/oops.php and domain.com/where.php but still not loaded

Comment: So you want to redirect on 404 and 5xx errors, right? What kind of redirect are you looking for?

Comment: @Gumbo yes, but i am not sure what kind of redirect i need. if is posible to redirect to a  custom page on error, that would be enough

Comment: There are internal redirects (or rewrites) where the redirection does only take place inside the server and is not visible externally. And there are external redirect where the redirection is instructed using a 3xx response pointing to a different URL and the user agent does request the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use custom error responses via [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument)?

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/internal-server-error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not-found.html
```

Comment: so shall i just place that in the .htaccess ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet That would do it. Did you read the information on the page I've linked to?

Comment: i did it and for example, please click http://keepyourlinks.com/blue to see that is not working

Comment: Do your error documents actually exist where you're specifying them? The page is saying it couldn't find the error document

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Your `oohps.php` (and `oops.php`) file doesn't seem to exist and your `where.php` is triggering a 500 error

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Check your error log. Something is causing that 500 error

Comment: How we can internally redirect, I mean when 404 error occurs, it redirects to error page. But how to redirect internally without changing url in status bar.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful I am able to redirect to index page on 404 error(page not found) by modifying "ErrorDocument" in /etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages file.

Thanks.....